# How do I check if a number is in an array from an input in python?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, list

Newbie here, why does it show a False value when clearly 5 is in the array. output below

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gMIwW.png)

```
arr = []

hidden_number = 5
bool = hidden_number in arr

no1 = int(input('number: '))
no2 = int(input('number: '))

arr.append(no1)
arr.append(no2)

print(arr)
print(bool)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because it is not when you ask the question.

Let us break it down, you create the array `arr` and define `hidden_number` as `5`.
But you do not add it to the array `arr`

```py
arr = []

hidden_number = 5
```

The you ask the question if `hidden_number` is in `arr`:

```py
bool = hidden_number in arr
```

As `arr` at this point is an empty array, the result of the question will be `false`.

Then you request the two numbers and add them to the list

```py
no1 = int(input('number: '))
no2 = int(input('number: '))

arr.append(no1)
arr.append(no2)
```

You do not ask again if `hidden_number` is in `arr` so therefore the value of `bool` does not change and remain false.

So when you print `arr` will show that it contains `[1, 5]` but `bool` will still be `false` as you did not change it.

```py
print(arr)
print(bool)
```

The `bool hidden_number in arr` will not automatically update as you add numbers to `arr`.

To change to what you want to achieve you need to do this

```py
arr = []

hidden_number = 5

no1 = int(input('number: '))
no2 = int(input('number: '))

arr.append(no1)
arr.append(no2)

doesArrContainsHiddenNumber = hidden_number in arr

print(arr)
print(doesArrContainsHiddenNumber)
```

Also please do not use the name `bool` for a variable as that is what the type of the value is and can be used in type hints.

Answer (score 0):

The value of your bool is set before all of the other elements have been added into the array so, it prints false because at point there are no other numbers in the array . Instead you should check for the hidden number in the array after all the other numbers have been added below is the fixed code.

```
arr = []

hidden_number = 52

no1 = int(input('number: '))
no2 = int(input('number: '))

arr.append(no1)
arr.append(no2)

bool = hidden_number in arr

print(arr)
print(bool)
```